# NSStatusItem set width

Tags: swift, nsstatusitem

Im trying to reduce the width the NSStatusItem takes up. As you can see, the picture im setting is not that wide, yet the blue area is much wider. How do i reduce this?

Im using this code:

`let icon = NSImage(named: "smaller.png")
statusItem.button!.image = icon`

[image]